# what does float cf = *(float *)&ci; in C do?

Tags: c, hex, decimal, type-punning

i'm trying to find out what this program prints exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
float bf = -62.140625;
int bi = *(int *)&bf;
int ci = bi+(1<<23);
float cf = *(float *)&ci;
printf("%X\n",bi);
printf("%f\n",cf);
}
```

This prints out:

C2789000
-124.281250

But what happens line by line ? I do not understand .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is undefined behavior according to c standard. Strict aliasing rule is violated by accesing an float object via int type and vice versa

Comment: Short answer: it's a tricky way of multiplying a `float` number by 2, by adding 1 to the exponent field.  But it's not a very good way: It's tricky, it's obscure, it's not particularly efficient, it's not portable and not guaranteed to work.  If you want to efficiently multiply a `float` by a power of 2 by adjusting the exponent, the recommended way is `cf = scalbnf(bf, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a convoluted way of doubling an 32bit floating point number by adding one to its exponent. Moreover it is incorrect due to violation of strict aliasing rule by accesing object if type `float` via type `int`.

Exponent is located at bits number 23 to 30. Adding `1<<23` increment the exponent by one what works like multiplication of the original number by 2.

Answer (score 1):

If we rewrite this program to remove pointer punning

```
int main() {
    float bf = -62.140625;
    memcpy(&bi, &bf, sizeof(bi));
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i += 8)
        printf("%02x ", ((unsigned)bi & (0xff << i)) >> i);
    bi += (1<<23);
    memcpy(&bf, &bi, sizeof(bi));;
    printf("%f\n",bf);
}
```

Float numbers have the format:
[image]

`-62.140625` has exponent == 0.

```
bi += (1<<23);
```

sets the exponent to `1` so the resulting float number will be `-62.140625 * 2^1` and it is equal to `-124.281250`. If you change that line to

```
bi += (1<<24);
```

it will set the exponent to `4` so the resulting float number will be `-62.140625 * 2^2` and it is equal to `-248.562500`.

Comment: You should probably remove `int bi = *(int *)&bf` entirely.

Comment: @AndrewHenle indeed -forgot about this line

Comment: Adding `1<<23` does not set the exponent to one. It adds one to the exponent field, which adds one to the exponent unless the field is 0, 1022, or 1023. And adding `1<<24` adds two to the field.

Comment: Avoid using sources that refer to the fraction portion of a floating-point number as a “mantissa.” That is an indication that either they are out of date or the author is not giving much attention and weight to technical accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

> `float bf = -62.140625;`

This creates a `float` object named `bf` and initializes it to −62.140625.

> `int bi = *(int *)&bf;`

`&bf` takes the address of `bf`, which produces a pointer to a `float`. `(int *)` says to convert this to a pointer to an `int`. Then `*` says to access the pointed-to memory, as if it were an `int`.

The C standard does not define the behavior of this access, but many C implementations support it, sometimes requiring a command-line switch to enable support for it.

A `float` value is normally encoded in some way. −62.140625 is not an integer, so it cannot be stored as a binary numeral that represents an integer. It is encoded. Reinterpreting the bytes memory as an `int` using `* (int *) &bf` is an attempt to get the bits into an `int` so they can be manipulated directly, instead of through floating-point operations.

> `int ci = bi+(1<<23);`

The format most commonly used for the `float` type is IEEE-754 binary32, also called “single precision.” In this format, bit 31 is a sign bit, bits 30-23 encode an exponent and/or some other information, and bits 22-0 encode most of a significand (or, in the case of a NaN, other information). (The significand is the fraction part of a floating-point representation. A floating-point format represents a number as ±*F*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *b* is a fixed base, *F* is a number with a fixed precision in a certain range, and *e* is an exponent in a certain range. *F* is the significand.)

`1<<23` is 1 shifted 23 bits, so it is 1 in the exponent field, bits 30-23.

If the exponent field contains 1 to 1021, then adding 1 to it increases the encoded exponent by 1. (The codes 0 and 1023 have special meaning in the exponent field. 1022 is a normal value, but adding 1 to it overflows the exponent in the special code 1023, so it will not increase the exponent in a normal way.)

Since the base *b* of a binary floating-point format is 2, increasing the exponent by 1 multiplies the number represented by 2. ±*F*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> becomes ±*F*•*b*<sup>*e*+1</sup>.

> `float cf = *(float *)&ci;`

This is the opposite of the previous reinterpretation: It says to reinterpet the bytes of the `int` as a `float`.

> `printf("%X\n",bi);`

This says to print `bi` using a hexadecimal format. This is technically wrong; the `%X` format should be used with an `unsigned int`, not an `int`, but most C implementations let it pass.

> `printf("%f\n",cf);`

This prints the new `float` value.